# Shopping Cart price rules not working for Category attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules

I Have a configurable product whose category is Cotton, but its simple product's category is different.. I have created a promotion rule for category "cotton" in magento backend.

If i apply rule to configurable products it check category of its associated simple products..

Why is it so..?

Answer (score 1):

Configurable product is nothing just a collection of simple products. This is because your promotion rule look for associated simple products.

**Catalog Price Rules ->** Only apply on product Pages.

**Shopping Cart Price Rules->** Only apply on cart page.

Comment: Ok, is there a way that when we create a configurable products and create its associated products by Quick edit..
It creates simple product by same category as of "Configurable product"

Comment: Also is it fine that cart rules work with simple products attributes..? is it default behavior..?

Comment: No quick edit option by default in Magento. Yes cart rules works with simple products attributes.

Answer (score 0):

> Enable Discount to Subproducts should be set to NO

[image]

Comment: Can you be kind and let me know the difference between "catalog price rule" and "Shopping cart price rules"..
As i can see i have created rules in "Shopping cart price rules" and screenshot shows "catalog price rule"

Comment: Also let me know how can we achieve the result in "Shopping cart price rules"

Comment: oh sorry.yes this is catalog price rule

Comment: so can we achieve this in  "Shopping cart price rules"

Comment: check  Catalog Price Rules [here](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html)

and Shopping Cart Price Rules[here](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html)

Comment: have you added any extension for Price ?

Comment: logically it should not happen as you have explained.

Comment: No, have not installed any extension